# “so long as” vs. “as long as”

Tags: conjunctions, formality, colloquialisms, comparisons, so-vs-as

I just googled the difference between *as long as* and *so long as*. The difference has alredy been discussed [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2025/39051). There are, it seems, two contexts for these expressions:

1. lengths and physical comparisons (time, distance, etc.)
   “This bridge is as long as that bridge.”
2. some logical implication or synonym for *provided that* or something like this. 
   “You can do that so long as you keep in mind that. . . .”

Somewhere else I found that you can use **both** expressions for context #2, but should avoid *so long as* in cases of context #1.

Now, [mmyers commented](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2025/so-long-as-vs-as-long-as#comment2595_2028) that *so long as* might be colloquial — or as he put it, “casual”. It seems that it’s possible to never use *so long as*, since according to what I have been told, you can use either expression in cases of context #1. Given that I am writing academic papers, my questions are:

1. Is *so long as* truly non-academic or non–high-style?
2. Should *so long as* therefore be avoided altogether?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer to your first question is no, *so long as* is neither particularly colloquial nor casual.   If anything, *so long as* has a more formal feel to it, not a less formal one, for reasons I shall presently make clear.

The answer to your second is no, *so long as* is not something that “should be avoided altogether”.

That said, there are native speakers whose dialects are for the most part missing *so long as*. This came as quite a surprise to me; I’ve always found this  a most peculiar lacuna, as I do not share it, but there you have it.  From personal experience, some people who do not have *so long as* in their dialects even seem to resent its use in others’.  I do not know why.

Older usage guides prescribed *as . . . as* for positive comparisons and *so . . . as* for negative ones.

- By then I was **as tall as** my mother, but not yet quite **so tall as** my father.

You can see this strong historical preference in [usage charts](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+as+long+as%2Cnot+so+long+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=5&share=):

[image: not-so-long-as picture]

But you can also see that that preference changed in the latter half of the twentieth century. You see the same sort of thing when you [graph *only as long as* against *not so long as*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=only+as+long+as%2Conly+so+long+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=5&share=), although this one lags behind the previous one by a decade or two:

[image: only-so-long-as picture]

Finally, if we relax the contextual restriction of a prefix *not* or *only*, the [resulting picture](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+long+as%2Cso+long+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=5&share=) paints a different picture:

[image: so-long-as picture]

That shows that when you include both positive and negative uses, *so long as* showed very strong gains against *as long as* during the first three quarters of the nineteenth and twentieth centuries, eventually even surpassing it, but that it became comparatively less popular during the last fifty years.

This trend is not limited to *long*; [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+as+easy+as%2Cnot+so+easy+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=5&share=) we see it with *not as easy as* versus *not so easy as*:

[image: not-so-easy-as picture]

This historical bias therefore has the effect of making *so . . . as* an “older” feel to it, perhaps therefore a more “formal” feel.  By the same token, it also necessarily confers a newer and less formal feel to *as . . . as* constructs.

If you read anything older than today’s broadsheets, you are bound to come across it, and you will find many speakers who continue to employ it.
So if you wish to come off as trendy and hip, certainly you may always simply use *as . . . as*.  However, you need to be aware that *so . . . as* also enjoys a long history in English, particularly in negative comparisons, and is ***not so* easily dismissed *as*** some would seem to wish it.

Indeed, as the previous sentence illustrates, *not so* is still perfectly productive and natural.  [Here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+as%2Cnot+so&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=5&share=) we see that it is even today virtually neck and neck with *not as* — and even that only very, very recently:

[image: not-so picture]

Comment: So, you would recommend using *so lang as* in context #2 and indeed even prefer it over *as long as*?

Comment: @ClintEastwood I wouldn’t make any recommendation for or against here. I use them both. I’d have to see a bunch larger context to say which way I might jump.

Comment: @ClintEastwood I’ve added some charts and notes that may help you here.

Comment: very, very helpful and informative!

Comment: Your comment re: those who resent others who use an idiom not in their own dialect. I find, admittedly anecdotally, that in such cases the first person judges the second as "talking down to them," flaunting a more high-falutin' vocabulary, perhaps intended to belittle the first speaker. More often than not it is simply differences in regional dialect, but I have found some people view this as an unnecessary and unwanted correction.